# check existance of object after uploading it to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to check if an object us successfuly uploaded to S3 just after uploading it.

```
PutObjectRequest putObjReq = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3Key, tmpArchivePath.toFile());
Upload upload = transferManager.upload(putObjReq);
upload.waitForCompletion();
boolean fileExistsAfter = s3Client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, s3Key);
```

that returns always true ,even if the object is not successfully uploaded. I think that is because of the Eventual Consistency,
example:
when the s3Key starts with / , it is not a valid key ,so the object will not be uploaded however it returns true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is a key that starts with `/` invalid?  Also, S3 is not eventually consistent.

Comment: My probleme is that doesObjectExist returns true even if the object does not exists in S3.

Comment: @fifan I think you're mistaken. The object *does* exist.

Comment: I've verified on S3 browser, that does not existe , and I know why , that's because the key starts with '/'.

Comment: I think you are mis-reading the situation. I don't use S3Browser, and it's not an authoritative source, but it might show an unnamed top-level folder or one simply named `/`. If so, click on it to see your object. Or, as mentioned, use the awscli to authoritatively verify the object's existence

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working correctly.

When you upload to a key such as `/dog.png`, you do indeed get an S3 object with the key `/dog.png`. You can see this if you run `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket//` (with extra trailing slash) instead of `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/`. You can also verify this by issuing a HeadObject request for the key `/dog.png`, which is effectively what the `doesObjectExist()` method does.

To verify the object exists using the awscli, run:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket mybucket --key /dog.png
```

So the upload succeeds and `doesObjectExist()` correctly returns true.

As a general rule, you probably want to avoid leading slash because it is confusing for people.